# create box-model in css

Tags: css, flexbox

I need a little bit help.

I would like to create the box-model like in the image, can someone help me.

I already have written code, but I don't know how to do to better.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1rF8.png)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
 background: #cecdcd;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u plz share the screenshot..I cant able to open the image..

Comment: I am not allowed to do

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1rF8.png image url

Comment: @masterOne use row grid system if you want to limit 3 or 4 in a row and try `justify-content: space-between;;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?
https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/rNBYyJy

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: calc((100% - 60px) / 3);
  background: #cecdcd;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 110px; */
  height: 110px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is possible to get the same height and width for the cards if the view port size change?

Comment: @masterOne, Only way, wich i know - is to use inner block, wich will save aspect-ratio of card. `padding-bottom` property using for this. https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/XWrzRrV Or you can ask it in new question.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid is much better for what you need

for example :

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 12px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
}
```

you can finfd more info here : https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your content to be squares (110px `width` and `height`) like in your case, I suggest you to work with grid.

This is a helpfull grid guide
http://grid.malven.co/

Otherwise I suggest to use `justicy-content: space-between` in your `.container` class

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
 background: #cecdcd;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  </div>
</div>






CSS

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
 background: #cecdcd;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 200ms;
}
```